# The localhost page isn’t working on MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

I want to use [Widget PDF](https://www.mediawikiwidgets.org/Widget:PDF) to embed PDF files on my MediaWiki pages. So at first installed [Extension:Widgets](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Widgets) on MediaWiki and it **seems** it is installed (I can see it in `Installed extensions` list in `Special:Version` of the Wiki). The I copied and pasted the entire source of the [PDF widget code](https://www.mediawikiwidgets.org/w/index.php?title=Widget:PDF&action=edit) page into a page called `Widget:PDF` on my Wiki:

```
<noinclude>__NOTOC__
<big>This widget allows you to '''embed PDF files''' on your wiki page.</big>

Created by [https://wiki.karlsregion.net/z/User:Wilhelm_Bühler Wilhelm Bühler] and adapted by [https://www.wikihoster.net Karsten Hoffmeyer].

== Using this widget ==
For information on how to use this widget, see [https://www.mediawikiwidgets.org/PDF widget description page on MediaWikiWidgets.org].

== Copy to your site ==
To use this widget on your site, just install [https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Widgets MediaWiki Widgets extension] and copy the [{{fullurl:{{FULLPAGENAME}}|action=edit}} full source code] of this page to your wiki as page '''{{FULLPAGENAME}}'''.
</noinclude><includeonly><object class="pdf-widget" data="<!--{$url|validate:url}-->" type="application/pdf" wmode="transparent" style="z-index: 999; height: 100%; min-height: <!--{$height|escape:'html'|default:680}-->px; width: 100%; max-width: <!--{$width|escape:'html'|default:960}-->px;"><param name="wmode" value="transparent">
<p>Currently your browser does not use a PDF plugin. You may however <a href="<!--{$url|validate:url}-->">download the PDF file</a> instead.</p></object></includeonly>
```

My PDF file is under this URL:

```
http://localhost/<wiki-name>/index.php/File:GraphicsandAnimations-Devoxx2010.pdf
```

And it's name is `File:GraphicsandAnimations-Devoxx2010.pdf`. So as described [here](https://www.mediawikiwidgets.org/PDF), I added this code to my Wiki page:

```
{{#widget:PDF
 |url=http://localhost/<wiki-name>/index.php/File:GraphicsandAnimations-Devoxx2010.pdf
 |width=750
 |height=1050
}}
```

But this error occured:

```
The localhost page isn’t working
localhost is currently unable to handle this request. 
HTTP ERROR 500
```

**What I did:**

1. Also I tried this (original example of the `Widget PDF`)

   ```
   {{#widget:PDF
    |url=https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/w/images/e/e9/SMW_quick_reference.pdf
    |width=750
    |height=1050
   }}
   ```

   But result was the same.
2. I read [Extension talk:Widgets](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension_talk:Widgets) but did not find any thing.
3. I opened Chrome DevTools (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>), but there was no error.

How I can solve the problem?

Edit:

After some times, I tried to uninstall [Widget PDF](https://www.mediawikiwidgets.org/Widget:PDF) and [Extension:Widgets](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Widgets) and reinstall them. So I removed `Extension:Widgets` files/folder from $IP/extensions/ and also deleted `Widget:PDF` page from Wiki. Then I installed `Extension:Widgets` again, but now, I can not open the Wiki pages at all (I see above error again), unless I delete `require_once "$IP/extensions/Widgets/Widgets.php";` from [LocalSettings.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:LocalSettings.php). So I even cannot try to load `Extension:Widgets`.

Now I see this error in `DevTools`:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Also after uninstalling `Extension:Widgets`, I tried [Extension:PDFEmbed](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PDFEmbed) and unfortunately again I saw above error.

Comment: HTTP 500 errors will be logged on your server (e.g. the PHP error log, depends on your [configuration](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:How_to_debug#PHP_errors)), not your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not solve above problem for using `extension`s to embedding PDF in MediaWiki. So finally I used [`$wgRawHtml`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgRawHtml) and uesed this code in my Wiki page:

```
<html>
<embed src="http://localhost/<wiki-name>/images/5/59/GraphicsandAnimations-Devoxx2010.pdf#page=14" width="1200px" height="500px" />
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No idea if this will help, but the first thing I would try would be replacing `localhost` with the IP address `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I have encountered with a new problem and cannot try your proposed way.  I edited  my question. Please see that again.